# Writing a lowercase to uppercase code for Arm A9 Cortex

Tags: arm, uppercase, lowercase

I get the algorithm for lowercase to uppercase but while writing the code with Assembly Language, I get confused with registers and if statements. Basically I'm trying to write a program that will make lowercase letters in terminal window > uppercase.

That is what I have done so far:

```
.equ    JTAG_UART_BASE,     0xFF201000

.text   /*executable code follows*/
.global     _start
_start:
    LDR     R1, =JTAG_UART_BASE
    LDR     R2, =MESSAGE
COUT:
    LDRB    R3,[R2],#1
    CMP     R3,#27
    BEQ     STOP
    STRB    R3,[R1]
    B       COUT
CIN:
    LDR     R4,[R1]
    AND     R5,R4,#0x8000
    CMP     R5,#0
    BEQ     CIN
    AND     R4,R4,#0x00FF
    STRB    R4,[R1]
    B       CIN
    
MESSAGE:
.asciz "Capitalize: "
```

I know that I need to compare the register to see if the input ASCII is between 96 and 122 and then do SUB #32 to convert it to Uppercase.

> The program is supposed to read the input from the terminal window and
> capitalize the lowercase letters, and quit when ESC is pressed (ASCII
> 27).

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question, show the code you have got so far, and specify what it is supposed to and what part of it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I added the code. Still new around here. Thanks!

Comment: Where is `STOP`?

Comment: `.asciz "Capitalize: "`, this does not have ASCII 27, and you never gonna reach `CIN`

Comment: and `CIN` does not have check for ASCII 27. And what the hell `AND     R5,R4,#0x8000` suppose to mean ?

Comment: AND     R5,R4,#0x8000 >>>>>>>> check RVALID(bit 15)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE You are right I should a section with STOP: B STOP